# jquery get statement

Tags: jquery, web-services, get

I am trying to use the jquery get statement:

```
$.get(urlAddress+".asmx", { question: quest },
  function(data){
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
  });
```

I don't know how to specify the method and how to get data

The HTTP headers are giving a 200 message (Ok) but I'm not getting any data back.

Any help please?

Comment: Is the urlAddress on the same domain or another?

Comment: What happens if you type the url into a browser directly? Have you tried using something like Fiddler or Firebug to sniff the request/response data?

Comment: I tried Firebug, I'm not so sure what I'm looking for though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to use a local proxy page to pull in the url if it's a cross-domain request, or use JSON.

For example, if I wanted to pull in `google.com` I send it to a local `/proxy?uri=http://google.com` and that grabs the content, returns it to me.

Comment: That's a very, very vague comment lacking information. Details please? You replied in 7 mins, seems like a rush and maybe you didn't read up on how to use it properly. Why not just go the server-side proxy route?

Comment: I had tried JSON prior to just the get method...should I post the code here or in my question? Maybe (most probably) I was doing somehtng wrong. I want to run this eventually on the iphone which is why the client-side would be ideal. (my quick replies are due to my constant refresh rate on this page ;) )

Comment: What about my proxy question?